# how to use multiprocessing inside class have to attribute are object and dict?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, multiprocessing

I have a class:

```
# myclass.py
class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self,*args):
        self.env = args[0] 
        self.mydict = args[1]

    def run(self):
        list_data = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
        pool = mp.Pool(3)
        for _ in tqdm(pool.imap_unordered(self.exefunction, list_data), total = len(a), desc = 'Main process'):
            pass
        pool.close()
        pool.join

    def exefunction(self,number):
        print(number)
        print(self.env)
        print(self.mydict)

# myenv.py
class MyEnv(object):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.database = args[0]
        self.host = args[1]
        self.port = args[2]
        self.user = args[3]
        self.pwd = args[4]
        self.sp = None
        self.param = None
        self.output_exception_msg = None
        self.output_sperror_msg = None
        self.pool = self.create_pool()

    def create_pool(self):
    self.pool = MySQLConnectionPool(pool_name=config.pool_name, pool_size=config.pool_size,
                               user=self.user, password=self.pwd, host=self.host, port=self.port, database=self.database)
    return self.pool

# main.py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    list_dict = [{ 1 : 3 , 5 : 10 }]
    env = MyEnv(**dbconfig)
    build_class = MyClass(env, list_dict)
    build_class.run()
```

`self.env` is an object that was created from another class.

When I call to function `run` I have a TypeError: `cannot serialize socket object`.

I know the problem is `MyClass` has an object and dict (I try to pass `self.env` and `self.mydict` are integer and it's working). I don't have any solution to fix it.

**UPDATE**: I opened a connection pool into my DB ( `self.env` contains that)

Comment: `multiprocessing` has to save data in file, run code in new process and load data from file. But some objects can't be saved in file. And this makes problem. You have to use pool only in main process and other processes should send information to main process using `queue`. Or every process should use own connection to database.

Comment: I run it in the Windows system, If I run it in the Linux system, can mode `fork` is do that instead of use `queue`?

Answer (score 0):

Each process runs in its own address space and therefore needs its own DB connection pool. So:

1. Class `MyEnv` should not explicitly call method `create_pool` from its `__init__` method; this pool-creation needs to be postponed until later.
2. Each process in the multiprocessing pool will have its own instance of class `MyEnv` as a global variable that gets initialized when the pool is created. `create_pool` will be called on each of these instances as part of that initialization.

I obviously am not in a position to test this, but you should get the general idea if minimal tweaking is necessary:

```py
def init_pool(the_env):
    global env
    env = the_env
    env.create_pool() # now create the pool

class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self,*args):
        self.env = args[0]
        self.mydict = args[1]

    def run(self):
        list_data = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
        # initialize the env global variable for each process in the process pool :
        pool = mp.Pool(3, initializer=init_pool, initargs=(self.env,))
        for _ in tqdm(pool.imap_unordered(self.exefunction, list_data), total = len(a), desc = 'Main process'):
            pass
        pool.close()
        pool.join

    def exefunction(self,number):
        print(number)
        print(env) # access global 
        print(self.mydict)

# myenv.py
class MyEnv(object):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.database = args[0]
        self.host = args[1]
        self.port = args[2]
        self.user = args[3]
        self.pwd = args[4]
        self.sp = None
        self.param = None
        self.output_exception_msg = None
        self.output_sperror_msg = None
        # don't create the pool now:
        self.pool = None

    def create_pool(self):
        self.pool = MySQLConnectionPool(pool_name=config.pool_name, pool_size=config.pool_size,
                               user=self.user, password=self.pwd, host=self.host, port=self.port, database=self.database)
        return self.pool

# main.py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    list_dict = [{ 1 : 3 , 5 : 10 }]
    env = MyEnv(**dbconfig)
    build_class = MyClass(env, list_dict)
    build_class.run()
```

Comment: Did this answer your question satisfactorily?